# Remove specific elements from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i got this code :

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "remove", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function (item) {
        var removeCounter = 0;

        for (var index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
            if (this[index] === item) {
                this.splice(index, 1);
                removeCounter++;
                index--;
            }
        }

        return removeCounter;
    }
});
```

And i try to remove from array specific elements with this code line :

```
var itemsRemoved = finalArray.remove(getBack);
```

But if i do console.log() it return 0 elements removed while my variable getBack is equal with 0 or other number and in array getBack value exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use `item.indexOf(this[index])` instead of `this[index] === item`.

Why? `item` is an Array and not a single Value:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "remove", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function (item) {
        var removeCounter = 0;

        for (var index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
            console.log(this[index], item);
            if (item.indexOf(this[index]) > -1) {
                this.splice(index, 1);
                removeCounter++;
                index--;
            }
        }

        return removeCounter;
    }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function is the return in console. The line with error is if (item.indexOf(this[index]) > -1) {

Comment: i get something like this http://jsfiddle.net/48JJL/1/ . Get back var store index drop and can change

Comment: Than you must specific your Question! You dont say that you have only single values on `getBack`. Datatype? String or Integer?

Comment: My bad. Sorry! :( data type is int

Comment: You can try to force both values to an String, for example,.. http://jsfiddle.net/48JJL/2/

Answer (score 0):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) about object comparison in js

A quick way to achieve it :

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "remove", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function (item) {
        var removeCounter = 0;

        for (var index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
            if (JSON.stringify(this[index]) === JSON.stringify(item)) {
                this.splice(index, 1);
                removeCounter++;
                index--;
            }
        }

        return removeCounter;
    }
});
```

Comment: Neither this... doesnt help :(

Comment: If you're only manipulate number, you can just use something like if (this[index].toString() === item.toString())